# Simple PHP relative path in a Joomla Tutorial

Tags: php, joomla

Considering this article [Developing a MVC component for Joomla](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_4_-_Creating_an_Administrator_Interface#Example_roll-out), following is the code to include the general template,

```
$pathToGeneralView = strchr(dirname(__FILE__), dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
$pathToGeneralView = str_replace(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),'.',$pathToGeneralView );
$pathToGeneralView = $pathToGeneralView . "/../../general/";  <-- returning path from current position. 
...
<?php require_once $pathToGeneralView . 'navigate.header.php'; ?>
<P>Do something    
<?php require_once $pathToGeneralView . 'navigate.footer.php'; ?>
```

With the file system hierarchy,

```
./com_compname/views/general/navigate.header.php  <-- sniplet code for the header
./com_compname/views/general/navigate.footer.php  <-- sniplet code for the footer
./com_compname/views/mngtable1/view.html.php
./com_compname/views/mngtable1/tmpl/default.php *
./com_compname/views/mngtable2/view.html.php
./com_compname/views/mngtable2/tmpl/default.php *
```

Since the general template component is just  under the `../../general` folder, why do the author bothering to use strchr, str_replace to deal with the folder path? Isn't it `../../general/navigate.header.php` or `../../general/navigate.footer.php` enough?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it work without the `$pathToGeneralView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding paths in joomla use the JURI class:

http://docs.joomla.org/JURI/base